# Convert Observable to Array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have the following 2 methods:

```
laatsteNieuws(): Observable<NieuwsItem[]> {
   return (this.nieuwsClient.pagina({ aantalItemsPerPagina: 10 }));
}

getArticle(id: string): Observable<ArticleDetails> {
     return combineLatest(this.nieuwsClient.item(id, null), this.laatsteNieuws()).pipe(
            map(([article, allArticles]) => ArticlesMapper.mapToArticleDetails(article, allArticles)));
}
```

In `getArticle()` I'm passing an article together with all articles to my mapper method. Currently, I am passing `allArticles` as an object but I need it to be an array. I tried to create a local var and use **Object.entries** but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `Object.values(allArticles)` where you pass in your object values, to make it an `array` instead of an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide more information (StackBlitz)?

If I understand the code correctly, `this.laatsteNieuws()` should actually return `NieuwsItem[]`. If in the `.mapToArticleDetails()` method an object was made from the array, the following might help:

```js
const arr = Object.keys(allArticles).forEach(article => {});
// or
const arr = Object.keys(allArticles).map(article => {});
```